# Reading a text file up to a certain character

Tags: c, parsing

Here's my dilemma. I have a file, and wish to read in all characters up until the program hits a '#', and ignore everything on that line after the '#'. For example

0 4001232 0        #comment, discard

This is frustrating, as it feels like there is  a very simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: i have a feeling that you want someone to provide you all the code.

Answer (score 7):

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
int c;
while ((c = getc(f)) != '#' && c != EOF)
   putchar(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read a line using [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/), read through this line till you get a '#' character.

Read an another line...

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways and examples of how to do it. Usually, the idea is to have a variable that holds the state (before #, after # , after \n etc.) and run in a while loop until EOF. an example you can see [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/86879-program-remove-comments-source.html) it's a program to remove C comments, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
filePointer = fopen("person.txt", "r");

do
{
    read = fgetc(filePointer);
    //stop when '#' read or when file ends
    if (feof(filePointer) || read == '#')
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("%c", read);
} while (1);

fclose(filePointer);
```

also you better check if file opened succesfully

```
if (filePointer == NULL)
{
    printf("person.txt file failed to open.");
}
else
{
    file operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how you are "reading" that.

I could, for example, just remove all of those comments with `sed 's/#.*//' <infile >outfile` in bash.

EDIT: However, if I was parsing it manually, I could simply (in my loop for parsing it) have

```
if(line[i]=='#') {
    continue;
}
```

which would stop parsing that line by exiting the loop.